# Chrome Developer Tools | Find in which script a function is

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

Is there a way to find where a function is placed into a script?
Like:

```
<div onclick="sayHello()">Hello</div>
```

In which script is the function **sayHello()** ?

Comment: Using the Chrome DevTools, you can type the name of the function into the console, hit Enter, then right-click on the returned value and click "*Show function declaration*". I'm not sure about other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hit f12, click on the console tab

type `sayhello` and hit enter

You'll see something like:
[image: snip of function in devtools]

Then double click on the line that appeared under your line.`f (e){.....`

That will jump you to the correct code.